# ASP.NET DropDownList SelectedIndex not changing on first element

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used to think my c# programming wasn't too bad, but today I am seriously questioning my head, something so small is defeating me...

I am trying to get a DropDownList to behave but we are not getting on today. I have a simple DropDownList in an ascx control which is dynamically loaded into an aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_SortBy" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">             
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Sort Alphabetically A to Z</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Sort Alphabetically Z to A</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and some code behind..

```
    private short SortBy = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ddl_SortBy.SelectedIndex = -1;
        this.ddl_SortBy.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SortBy_SelectedIndexChanged);

        if (!IsPostBack)
            SearchDirectory();
    }

    public void ddl_SortBy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SortBy = Convert.ToInt16(this.ddl_SortBy.SelectedItem.Value);
        SearchDirectory();
    }
```

I can never get the first item to trigger the selected index change event - as the SearchDirectory() function is not called. I can understand that it's possibly the case that when the control loads the first item IS selected so when selecting, the index isn't actually changing.

I have tried setting the selected item index to -1, and ClearSelection() on page load, but no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I've also tried putting the event call on the DropDownList using `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and remove the first two lines in the Page_Load, and same result.

Comment: The first thing you do on every page request is set the selected index to a static value.  As far as the rest of the code is concerned, it never changes.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Are you expecting the event to occur on initial load?  Or are you experiencing an issue where "reselecting" the initial item is not working?

Comment: No, on page load it works fine as it will just use a value of 0 defined by `SortBy`, and then when the second option in the dropdownlist is selected it works fine, but when selecting the first one after that, nothing happens, it just posts back and does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are always resetting the `SelectedIndex` to -1 on every postback:

```
this.ddl_SortBy.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

So put that also in the postback-check:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    this.ddl_SortBy.SelectedIndex = -1;
    SearchDirectory();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, I was clutching at straws with that and same thing happens with it removed.

Comment: I've noticed that the master page the aspx page is in has view state switched off, i've turned that on and it works now... Issue now is I don't want the view state on for all pages in my site :-/ Thanks though Tim

Comment: @danrichardson: I assume that the dynamical part of your usercontrol loading is causing this issue. So you should show us how you're adding the usercontrol to the page. Are you recreating it on every consecutive postback with the same id as before? **Edit**: I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: It's being added from another user control which is being loaded in the same way. Like so `System.Web.UI.UserControl ctl = ((System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).LoadControl(CntrlSrc) as System.Web.UI.UserControl;`  - I don't have any issues with a contact form control which is loaded in the same way, just this dropdownlist

Comment: and then that is added to a place holder control in the control it's loaded into

Comment: This is probably the answer for most people arriving at this (which seems quite a lot) so I'm going to mark this as the answer. But my own answer solved my problem with this as it was more related to the view state on my master page I think - was a while ago now.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself in the same need to execute a change event on Page_Load like you're expecting.. the thing is that I perceived that in ASP.NET before to put some ListItems it set .SelectecIndex to 0.

So if I put some thing like this.ddl_SortBy.SelectedIndex = -1, after that the debugger still shows 0... so it never turn on -1 and never executes the change event. It's like if ASP.NET always considers the first ListItem as the selected one when nothing (-1) is selected, so force it do -1 or 0 never calls change event at the first.

Searching a bit more: "The default value is 0, which selects the first item in the list."

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex(v=vs.100).aspx so I think we must force the call to event like:
ddl_SortBy_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);

Answer (score 0):

Move the event handler assignment to OnInit from OnLoad and delete the SelectedIndex line.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ddl_SortBy.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SortBy_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!IsPostBack) 
        SearchDirectory(); 
}
```

Comment: Same problem doing it that way also.

Comment: @danrichardson - Did you copy/paste the control from another page?  If so, delete it, save the file and type it from scratch.  And keep the event assignment in the OnInit, that's where it should be.

Comment: Nope, all written from scratch anyway.

Comment: @danrichardson - create a new project and add your drop down there.  No master page and static items.  Add the event handler in OnInit and see if that works.  If it does, there might be something wrong with your current page.  Try "cleaning" the project, deleting temp files, recompiling.  Might help clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

My master page view state was switched off which is why it wasn't working. Though that is not what I want to allow.

My solution was to revert to real form submission data retrieval using Request.Form.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
            SortBy = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form[this.ddl_SortBy.UniqueID]);

        // search directory
        SearchDirectory();
    }
```

Works absolutely fine now :)
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

How about this simple workaround. Set the first item in the drop down to be:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="-1">(choose how to sort)</asp:ListItem>
```

That way, the selected index will change and the event will fire when the user selects the desired sort order.

Remove extra fiddling with the drop down from the code behind first.

Comment: Not really a good solution as it means changing what I want to show, and is contradicting what I want the code to do by default - which is to sort by the first item.